# Why isnt XCode 5 adding constraints in storyboard as I move views around using autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode5

My app was working and was ready for submit yesterday. I stupidly upgraded xcode. Some views needed adjustment. I got all but one working.

The one that isnt working is

View

> Scrollview
>
> > Other child views

The problem is the scrollview doesnt scroll. User interaction is checked. I even recreated the entire view from scratch and relinked everything to my class.h and segweys.

I noticed that there are no constraints setup for this scrollview, or for any of the child views. When moving views around it no longer creates the purple, system constraints automatically. Before this I had converted the purple constraints to blue constraints and then linked them to the .h file so I could remove them and then apply my own constraints. But now, since there are none being generated I can't convert them to blue to remove. When I add them manually using the pin menu in story board, I get errors when navigating to that view in the simulator because of Prototype constraints generated at run time.

When I click on the view and hit Reset to Suggested constraints it doesnt add any...

How can I make xcode add the purple constraints automatically as I move views around?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to automatically add the constraints as you move the view around. If your view doesn't have any constraints, you should choose "Add Missing Constraints", not "Reset To Suggested Constraints"(this should add similar constraints to that you would have gotten automatically in Xcode 4.6). Once you've added the initial constraints, then when you move the view around, you can update the constraints to reflect your new position with "Update Constraints" or command-shift-equals.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this in a couple days and let you know if that worked.